# Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. We received a bad request. (AADSTS50011: The reply address)

Tags: django, django-allauth, office365api

I'm building a Django web app that allows users to sign in using their Office 365 account through allauth. However, when I try to log in I get the error

> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

We received a bad request.

> Additional technical information:
>   Correlation ID: [correlation-id]
>   Timestamp: 2017-09-18 03:19:43Z
>   AADSTS50011: The reply address 'https://localhost:8000/accounts/office365/login/callback/' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: '[app_id]'. More details: not specified"

However, I did put the redirect URL in - see the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Oxe.jpg).

Not sure where my configuration error is.

Comment: Url in the image is clearly different from the url in the error message? (`localhost` vs. `127.0.0.1`). It's also possible it's being rejected because that's not a routable address.

Comment: `localhost` having loopback address as `127.0.0.1` @mindcruzer

Comment: @user3005684  refer this https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/office-365   might helps you

Comment: I'm an idiot. dk why I put 127.0.0.1 and couldnt catch that... its working now. thanks